# C++/CLI exporting global symbols in assembly

Tags: c++-cli

I've got a situation where I can't change a CLI header that declares several symbols in the global scope, and then those symbols are then used by a function which IS inside a namespace, and that function is exported in an assembly I need to make use of.

Below is a bit of puedo code to help illustrate the Visual Studio setup. Also, I'm using the 2008 toolchain which is pre C++11 making the 'enum class' a managed object. Also note that it also doesn't have the access specifier (I did not write this) which makes it private.

```
ExportingAssembly.vcxproj
|->SomeHeader.h
| |->enum class SomeSymbol
|->SomeSource.c
  |->SomeNamespace
    |->void SomeFunction(SomeSymbol arg)

ImportingAssembly.vcxproj
|->Ref ExportingAssembly
|->ImportingSource.c
  |->Using SomeNamespace;
  |->void MyFu(){ SomeSumbol a = 0; SomeFunction(a); }
```

The problem is that those global symbols are obviously not visible to the importing assembly and if I include the header for those symbols it results in an incompatibility between my assembly and the one I'm importing

```
error C2664: 'ExportAssemblyNamespace::SomeFunction(SomeSymbol arg)': can't   
convert parameter 1 from 'SomeSymbol" to 'SomeSymbol'
```

Now I CAN change the exported assembly (the project file and/or the source file) so I just hope I can somehow make those global symbols part of the exported assemblies' namespace so the importing assembly will see them. Or failing that, somehow locate the global symbols in the exported assembly (I can see the global symbols are in the PE MetaData Tables).

Any ideas. Or is a symbol without an access specifier private and impossible to make use of via referencing the assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or is a symbol without an access specifier private and impossible to make use of via referencing the assembly?

Yes, a symbol without an access specifier is private. It's not quite "impossible" to make use of; the only way is via reflection.

The fact that you have some things in a namespace, and some not, doesn't matter here. But you should have your function as part of a class, since global functions aren't part of the CLR. (C++/CLI creates a class to hold the global functions, but it's not a public class, and I think it has an invalid name anyway.)

Add the keyword `public` to your enum, and enclose your function in a `public ref class`.

Comment: Thanks. Good spot with 'SomeFunction', it was meant to be a class not a namespace that was wrapping it (The actual project has it as a static in side a class).

I'll have a go at seeing if I can get reflection to work.

Comment: Since you obviously have access to the source code to both projects, why are you not making the enum & class public? Since you obviously want to use them in another project, that's what `public` is for.

Comment: It would result in a very large re-write, which even though it would create code that is much more correct, I can't justify the cost of to fix my problem.